# Spring Cloud Gateway: unname query parameter

Tags: java, filter, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

Is possible to add an unnamed request parameter to a request?
I need to mask behind spring cloud gateway this url (Microsoft Report Server)

```
https://myrshost/reportserver?/Sales/YearlySalesByCategory&rs:Format=PDF&id=XXX
```

And the report path `/Sales/YearlySalesByCategory` is passed without a parameter name and I can't use `RewritePath` filter to manipulate it.
The `id` parameter must be passed from the external request